# Network issue migrating an VMWare guest to an OpenVZ container

Tags: linux, networking, vmware-server, openvz

I've migrated a server from vmware to openvz, both are running on the same physical host (I plan to eliminate vmware).  If I give the new openvz container a new IP anybody on the LAN and outside network can get to it with no problem, but as soon as I change its IP address to the original IP (that the vmware guest used to have), only the host server and its contained virtual machines can get to it.

I have made sure to change the IP on the old virtual machine.

Comment: You might be running into an ARP caching issue - have you verified the ARP cache contents of the hosts which are unable to connect?

Comment: I only tried deleting the ARP record for that IP on the host server, but it complained that there was no record (even though it was listed when i issued 'arp').  ARP is one of those things I don't understand much about, do you think I might need to clear that cache on our sonicwall router?

Comment: Can the new container access the outside network? Have you tried traceroute to and from the container?

Comment: It turned out to be the arp cache on our router. @syneticon-dj : if you post an answer I'll accept it, since your comment was invaluable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the hint as an answer:

You might be running into an ARP caching issue - have you verified the ARP cache contents of the hosts which are unable to connect?

Answer (score 0):

My openvz host still had a static route to the VM I migrated from openvz to KVM.

A `route del -host <ip_addr>` fixed the issue for me.